# Sass with BEM, inherit selector

Tags: css, sass, bem

I'm using Sass 3.4.1 and BEM so my scss is:

```
.photo-of-the-day{
    &--title{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

and I want every time hover over `.photo-of-the-day` something happen with title, that's pretty common so usually in css:

```
.photo-of-the-day:hover .photo-of-the-day--title{
    font-size:12px
}
```

the thing is using BEM this is the only way I found and looks kinda ugly

```
.photo-of-the-day{
    &--title{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    &:hover{
        background: red;
        /* this is ugly */
        .photo-of-the-day--title{
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
}
```

so I was wondering if I can inherit `.photo-of-the-day` selector and use it inside the hover to avoid copy again the full selector.

Ideally would be something like:

```
.photo-of-the-day{
    &--title{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    &:hover{
        background: red;
        &&--title{
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
}
```

Or something close to comeback to the parent selector for BEM. Is it possible?

Comment: I made mixin for this. Here my another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293891/sass-css-target-parent-class-from-child/49426503#49426503

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you insist on nesting everything, the best you can do is this:

```
.photo-of-the-day {
    $root: &;
    &--title{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    &:hover{
        #{$root}--title {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this syntax:

```
.photo-of-the-day {
    &--title {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    &:hover &--title {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is if I do that solution I lost the hover scope so can not do: ``&:hover{
    cursor: pointer; background: red;
    ...
    .photo-of-the-day--title{
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }``

Comment: @alexrqs And?  There's no rule that says you have to nest everything.  A solution that has nesting is actually more verbose.

Comment: @alexrqs You have to use `&:hover { /* ... */ }` independently of the `&:hover &--title`.

Comment: @alexrqs - you are absolutely right. while this works, it would mean repeating the `:hover` selector how many times needed, loosing any DRY aspects SASS gives you. very sad.