# Nesting tag name into class style in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I want to nest selector for `<a>` tag inside a class `.class-name`, in order to apply those styles only for elements who has both the `<a>` tag and the class `.class-name` using SCSS. What I want to do can be performed the following way:

```css
.class-name {
  font-size: 40px;
 }
 
 a.class-name {
   color: #ff6666;
 }
```

```html
<div class="class-name">Hello</div>
<a class="class-name" href="#">World!</a>
```

I've tried two different ways in SCSS using `&` parent selector

```
# successfully transpiled but no change
.class-name {
  font-size: 40px;
  &a {
    color: #ff6666;
  }
}

# Got an error trying to transpile
.class-name {
  font-size: 40px;
  a& {
    color: #ff6666;
  }
}
```

I do **not** want to nest the other way around (`.class-name` inside `a`).

Comment: or a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268051/sass-combining-parent-using-ampersand-with-base-element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its not nesting, its two different elements, try as below to achieve as you want

```
.class-name {
  font-size: 40px;
}

a.class-name {
  color: #ff6666;
}
```

Or in nested way

```
a{
   &.class-name{
    color: #ff6666;
   }
}
```

It not possible to `target parent class from child`

Get more details from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293891/sass-css-target-parent-class-from-child)

Comment: That's the solution I already gave in my question, but it's not the scss way. If a was a class name, it was possible to nest using & parent selector

Comment: About your last edition nesting elements... I do not want to nest the other way around (.class-name inside a). Also, where in your solution would I place font-size?

Comment: This is `scss` to generate `css` as you mentioned

Comment: `a.class-name` is specific to add `color: #ff6666;` but `font-size: 40px;` is already added by `.class-name` before this.

Comment: @ArthurCantarela : Can you try and then let us know ?

Comment: I've undo my down vote, but it's not the solution I'm looking for. To make it clear, i know how to perform this, I'm looking for an specific scss way to improve my skills and create possible better practices

Comment: @ArthurCantarela : check some discussion [here](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand)

Comment: @ArthurCantarela : [its not possible as here already mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293891/sass-css-target-parent-class-from-child)

Comment: Edit your answer with those references so I can accept it

Comment: @ArthurCantarela : I have edited my ans. BTW Which method you applied ?

Comment: it works but the `a.class-name` is not `SCSS` style.

Answer (score 13):

I think you have to use [Sass' @-root](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_at-root__at-root).

```
.class-name {
  font-size: 40px;

  @at-root {
    a#{&} {
      color: #ff6666;
    }
  }
}
```

Personally I don't find it very pleasing to read, and more important difficult fo find via ctrl+f in a file (if you don't have sourcemaps)

Edit: will break if the whole block is nested into something else...