# What is the best SASS practice of writing child selector while parent has hover

Tags: sass, css-selectors, bem

I have a doubt of writing child selector when I have a hover event in parent.

say I have HTML like this,

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="root__element">
    <div class="root__sub-element" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In sass,

```
.root {
  $root: &;

  &__element {
    &:hover {
      #{$root}__sub-element {color: red;} // question comes here, why 
                                          // not using .root_sub-
                                          // element?
    }
  }
}
```

what I want is hover event happens in `root__element`, color change in `root__sub-element`.
Should I use ampersand to keep SASS or I would directly use '.root__sub-element'?

Comment: I made mixin for this. Here my another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293891/sass-css-target-parent-class-from-child/49426503#49426503

Comment: `$root = &;` should be `$root : &;`

Comment: @Sachink nice catch :)

Answer (score 0):

You should **Keep SASS.**

- I noticed you tagged 'bem' in your question.
- As per BEM, your block element class to continue with your prefix of last child class.  http://getbem.com/naming/

**POINT 1:**

If you have another element with the same behavior. the hardcoded class `.root__sub-element` will break. please consider the following sass code with multiple root classes.

SASS Code :

```
$roots: root, newroot;
@each $r in $roots {
  .#{$r}{
    $root: &;
    &__element {
      &:hover {
        #{$root}__sub-element {color: red;}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**POINT 2:**

This is very rare or not suggested practice, but suppose in case your root block class `.root` changed to `.newroot`. as per bem, your child classes will change with new prefix.
 Here, hardcoded class `.root__sub-element` will break, you need to changes it to all area manually.

*Otherwise*:

CSS is:

```
.newroot__element:hover .root__sub-element {
  color: red;
}
```

Expected CSS:

```
.newroot__element:hover .newroot__sub-element {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Very nice explanation. In both scenario using variable is the only choice. BTW, I do use BEM in naming, but not very BEM-ish, cannot convince myself to use B__E__E__E__E--M :)