# Migration Stylus to SASS

Tags: css, sass, stylus

I hope you can help me, for years I have been using Stylus as a CSS preprocessor but unfortunately the community is very small, I am currently switching to Sass and I want to migrate a complete project from Stylus to Sass, in the middle of the migration a problem arose and I would like to know how to do this in Sass.

```
.service_list_item
    display: grid
    position: relative
    padding: 0 1.072rem
    justify-items: center

    &:hover
        & ^[0]_icon // <=== This line
            background-color: $accentColor
```

The line I left selected I am pointing to the parent of the class and concatenating **"_icon"** to create a new class that compiled would look like this.

```
.service_list_item {
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 1.072rem;
    justify-items: center;
}
.service_list_item:hover .service_list_item_icon {
    background-color: #e3c1c1;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SASS CSS: Target Parent Class from Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293891/sass-css-target-parent-class-from-child)

Comment: Check out the 3rd answer of assigning a variable under the parent selector. I don't think the top answer about `@at-root` will help you here.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment, no, unfortunately this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple solutions to do what you're willing to do.

- The first wood be to assign a new variable for `.service_list_item`:

```
.service_list_item {
    $root: &;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 1.072rem;
    justify-items: center;

    &:hover {
        #{$root}_icon {
            background-color: $accentColor
        }
    }
}
```

- Another solution, would be to write `&:hover` and `&_icon` on the same line:

```
.service_list_item {
    $root: &;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 1.072rem;
    justify-items: center;

    &:hover &_icon {
        background-color: $accentColor
    }
}
```

Both will output the same.
I would use the first if I need to use `$root` more than once in the selector, the second option is less verbose, but if you need  rule for `&:hover`, you'll need a new line...
It's up to you to see what fits you the best.